# Pygame blank white screen

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to pygame and trying to simulate a table tennis table for a school project starting with just plotting the the vertices and lines. When I run the code, pycharm only shows me a blank white screen in the pygame window and python doesn't give me any errors, not sure what Iv'e done wrong. Any suggestions?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

verts = (
    (-1,-1,-1),
    (-1,-1,1),
    (-1,1,-1),
    (-1,1,1),
    (1,-1,-1),
    (1,-1,1),
    (1,1,-1),
    (1,1,1)
    )
edges = (
    (0,1),
    (0,2),
    (0,3),
    (0,4),
    (2,1),
    (2,3),
    (2,7),
    (6,3),
    (6,4),
    (6,7),
    (5,1),
    (5,4),
    (5,7)
    )
areas = (
    (0,1,2,3),
    (3,2,7,6),
    (4,5,1,0),
    (1,5,7,2),
    (4,0,3,6)
    )
def table():
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)

    for surf in areas:
        glColor3fv((0,0,255))
        for vert in surf:
            glVertex3fv(verts[vert])
    glEnd()


def main():
    pygame.init()
    display = (1000,800)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(display,DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)
    gluPerspective(45,(display[0]/display[1]), 0.1,50.0)
    glTranslatef(-20,-10,-50)
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        glRotatef(0,0,0,0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        table()
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(60)
        red = [255,0,0]
        screen.fill(red)
        display.fill[red]

main()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: @jhpratt didn't fix the blank screen

Comment: I didn't say it would. That's for _us_, so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Trying to call `screen.fill(red)` generates an error: `pygame.error: Cannot call on OPENGL Surfaces`. The next line makes less sense `display.fill[red]`, it'll generate an error because `display` is a tuple of your screen size.

Answer (score 1):

Your code indentation look bad. Python indentation is fundamental to run a code.

In your code, some function names and functions seem strange too. Like call ***Table()*** for call ***table()***(python is case sensitive) for example.

Answer (score 1):

Change the last three lines of `def main():` from:

```
red = [255,0,0]
screen.fill(red)
display.fill[red]
```

To two lines:

```
glClearColor(0.7, 0, 0, 1)
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are facing, but I have run plenty of games and pygame worked very well.

Recently my Mac did an update and screwed with python. I pip installed pygame again, and tried running a game I created that worked very well before. The screen was all white. Music was working fine and the game was actually working because I could hear the sounds I attached to button presses.

No logging errors show up in the terminal to explain this. You would think that the game is running fine.

If your problem is like mine, somebody probably screwed up a release.

Comment: How did you fix this issue in the end?

Comment: I didn't. I haven't been able to get this working since posting. I'm trying again but not having luck. This was all done in python2. I recently just tried again in python 3 and it works. However, there are many games that have been written for python 2 and I really don't like that they are suddenly all broke.